# pass view parameter to decorator and redirect to login view

Tags: django, view, decorator

Here is my manage view, I need a decorator to instead of the "event_session_check", but I don't know how to pass "event_key" to decorator, so I wrote "event_session_check" ...

The "event_session_required" will verify the ID and password in EventSet model not auth.User, please help me ...

```
"""
def event_session_required():
    def _session_required(view_func):
        @wraps(view_func)
        def __session_required(request, *args, **kwargs):
            next = request.get_full_path()
            event_key = kwargs.pop('event_key', '')
            session_key = 'event_%s' % event_key
            print session_key
            login_path = reverse('event-manage-login', args=[event_key])
            redirect_url = login_path + '?next=' + next
            try:
                session = request.session.get(session_key)
                if session is None:
                    raise ValueError('Cannot use None at session value')
            except KeyError as e:
                messages.error(request, 'session key not found')
                return redirect(redirect_url)
            except ValueError as e:
                messages.error(request, e.message)
                return redirect(redirect_url)
            else:
                if session:
                    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
                else:
                    return redirect(redirect_url)
        return __session_required
    return _session_required
"""


def event_session_check(request, event_key):

    session_key = 'event_%s' % event_key
    if session_key not in request.session or request.session[session_key] != True:

        next = request.get_full_path()
        next = urlquote_plus(next)
        next = iri_to_uri(next)

        login_path = reverse('event-manage-login', args=[event_key])
        redirect_url = login_path + '?next=' + next

        return redirect_url

    return None

#@event_session_required
def event_manage(request, event_key):
    check_session = event_session_check(request, event_key)
    if check_session:
        return redirect(check_session)

    try:
        eventset = EventSet.objects.get(key=event_key)
    except EventSet.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    template = 'event/manage.html'
    return render(request, template, {'eventset' : eventset })


#@event_session_required
def event_manage_detail(request, event_key, detail_key:
    check_session = event_session_check(request, event_key)
    if check_session:
        return redirect(check_session)

    try:
        eventset = EventSet.objects.get(key=event_key)
    except EventSet.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    event_details = eventset.details.all()

    template = 'event/manage_detail.html'
    return render(request, template, {
        'eventset' : eventset,
        'event_details': event_details
    })
```

## FIXED!!!

Yes! Thanks @V Stoykov and @Aldian Fazrihady, finally I fixed my code. It works great now.

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('event.views.manage',
    url(r'^(?P<event_key>\w+)/login$', 'event_login', name='event-manage-login'),
    url(r'^(?P<event_key>\w+)/logout$', 'event_logout', name='event-manage-logout'),
    url(r'^(?P<event_key>\w+)/manage$', 'event_manage', name='eventset.manageid '),
    url(r'^(?P<event_key>\w+)/edit$', 'event_manage_detail', name='event-manage-detail')
)
```

decorator.py:

```
def event_session_required(view_func):
    def _session_required(request, *args, **kwargs):
        next = request.get_full_path()
        event_key = kwargs.get('event_key', '')

        login_path = reverse('event-manage-login', args=[event_key])
        redirect_url = login_path + '?next=' + next

        session_key = 'event_%s' % event_key
        try:
            session = request.session.get(session_key)

        except KeyError:
            return redirect(redirect_url)

        except ValueError:
            return redirect(redirect_url)

        else:
            if session is None:
                del request.session[session_key]
                return redirect(redirect_url)

            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return _session_required
```

manage.py

```
def event_login(request, event_key):
    ...

    try:
        eventset = EventSet.objects.get(key=event_key)
    except EventSet.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    next request.GET.get('next', '')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if eventset.manageid == request.POST.get('manageid', '') and eventset.managepwd == request.POST.get('managepwd', '') and eventset.manageid and eventset.managepwd:
        ......
            return redirect(next)
        else:
            ......

    ...

@event_session_required
def event_manage(request, event_key):

    try:
        eventset = EventSet.objects.get(key=event_key)
    except EventSet.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    template = 'event/manage.html'
    return render(request, template, {'eventset' : eventset })


@event_session_required
def event_manage_detail(request, event_key, detail_key:

    try:
        eventset = EventSet.objects.get(key=event_key)
    except EventSet.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    event_details = eventset.details.all()

    template = 'event/manage_detail.html'

    return render(request, template, {
        'eventset' : eventset,
        'event_details': event_details
    })


def event_logout(request, event_key):

    session_key = 'event_%s' % event_key
    try:
        del request.session[session_key]
    except:
        pass

    return redirect(reverse('event-manage', args=[event_key]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see one problem and one possible problem.

The problem is that your decorator `event_session_required` does not accept any arguments. Instead the real decorator is the function `_session_required` inside it.

With your current code (if uncommented), if you want to decorate a function you need to **call** the decorator. Example:

```
@event_session_required()
def event_manage(request, event_key):
    ....
```

If you don't need to pass any arguments to `event_session_required` you can make it to receive `view_func` directly and remove `_session_required` function.

```
def event_session_required(view_func):
    @wraps(view_func)
    def __session_required(request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

@event_session_required
def event_manage(request, event_key):
    ...
```

And there is also one possible problem in your wrapped view `__session_required`. I don't know how you describe the URLs in `urls.py` but from what I see I think that it is as positional argument instead of keyword. In your `__session_required` you expect keyword.

You have two options:

1. To change your URLs definition to use keyword arguments
2. To be sure that every function that will be decorated with `event_session_required` receive `event_key` as first positional argument (after `request`) and change your `__session_required` to expect it as first argument instead of keyword.

I will suggest No.1

Answer (score 0):

I never create the outermost function like your event_session_required.
I always go directly to function _session_required(view), so the decorator will be @_session_required.

Instead of searching event_key in kwargs, try to find it in args instead.